# AngularJS filter on multiple values of one field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to be able to filter on two different values of one field of an object. Take the following example.

```
$scope.products = [
    {name:"Apple",type:"fruit"},
    {name:"Grape",type:"fruit"},
    {name:"Orage",type:"fruit"},
    {name:"Carrot",type:"vegetable"},
    {name:"Milk",type:"dairy"}
]
```

With the filter `ng-repeat="item in products | filter:{type:'fruit'}"`. I can get all of the fruits. But what if I want to get all of the fruits and vegetables. I tried

```
ng-repeat="item in products | filter:{type:['fruit','vegetable']}"
```

But that didn't work. I figure there should be a simple solution to this, but I couldn't find it.

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QHtD8/)**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a filter function instead:

```
$scope.fruitOrVeg = function(product){
    return product.type == 'fruit' || product.type == 'vegetable';
};

<li ng-repeat="item in products | filter:fruitOrVeg">{{item.name}}</li>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/QHtD8/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for AngularJs 1.8 is

`| filter:{property:value1}||{property:value2}`

for example

`| filter:{someIntegerVariable:1}||{someIntegerVariable:2}`

`| filter:{someStringVariable:'this'}||{someStringVariable:'that'}`