# ng-table filtering of concatenated values from scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable

I created an application in AngularJs with ngTable, I'm using ngTable to display the user data and by requirements, I must use a single column in a table to filter by first and last name, which are separated in the `$scope` and I concatenate the result on the table cell. But I cannot filter by the concatenation.

I've tried to create a custom filter as it's outlined on http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/11 to accomplish this task, unsuccessfully so far.

I could modify the scope when the data is received, by looping through the array, but the result set is expected to be pretty large and I don't think that'd be the correct way to do it.

Below is a simplified example. Is there an 'Angular Way' to filter by the concatenated string, using a model or a filter?.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('IndexCtrl', function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams) {
     $scope.people = [{
        "id": 1,
            "firstName": "Chuck",
            "lastName": "Norris",
    }, {
        "id": 2,
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Lennon",
    }, {
        "id": 3,
            "firstName": "Bender",
            "lastName": "Rodriguez",
    }];
    $scope.peopleCopy = $scope.people;
    $scope.mytable = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10,          // count per page
        sorting: {
            name: 'desc'
        }
        
    }, {
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
           $scope.people = angular.copy($scope.peopleCopy);
           var filteredData = $filter('filter')($scope.people, params.filter());
             $scope.people = $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy());
             $defer.resolve($scope.people);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table/0.3.0/ng-table.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
    <table border="1" ng-table="mytable" show-filter="true">
            <tr ng-repeat="person in $data">
                <td sortable="id" data-title="'Id'">{{person.id}}</td>
              
                <!--td I want to sort by firstName + lastName -->
                <td sortable="firstName" filter="{ 'firstName': 'text' }" data-title="'Name'">{{person.firstName +' '+ person.lastName}}</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: A custom filter can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736518/angularjs-filter-on-multiple-values-of-one-field

Comment: This was indeed the way I solved it. thanks a lot. I'll post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utimately, I solved the filtering by using a simple filter (shown below). that adds the value `person.fullName` to the current object collection used in ng-repeat by the table

```
 $scope.getFullName = function(person) {
     return person.fullName = person.name + ' ' + person.lastName;
 }
```

and referencing it in the ngTable's  ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in $data | filter:getFullName">
```

Then using the newly added value to the object with `{{person.fullName}}` in where needed (in the filter and cell value).

```
<td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'person.fullName'" 
    filter="{ 'fullName': 'text' }" header-class="ngtable-header"
    class="ngtable-td">{{ person.fullName }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a filter function that looks at both fields

```
 $scope.people = [{
    "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Chuck",
        "lastName": "Norris",
}, {
    "id": 2,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Lennon",
}, {
    "id": 3,
        "firstName": "Bender",
        "lastName": "Rodriguez",
}];

$scope.filterLastAndFirst= function(person, searchParam){
    return person.firstName.indexOf(searchParam) !== -1 || person.lastName.indexOf(searchParam) !== -1;
};

<li ng-repeat="item in products | filterLastAndFirst: searchParam">{{item.name}}</li>
// where $scope.searchParam is defined
```

Or a filter

```
app.filter('lastAndFirstFilter', function(){
    return function(objectArray, searchParam){
        var toReturn = [];
        // parse the array and search for a parameter.
        angular.forEach(objectArray, function(value){
            if(value.lastName.indexOf(searchParam) !== -1 || value.firstName.indexOf(searchParam) !== -1)
                toReturn.push(value);
        });
        return toReturn; // return the array 
    }
});

// used like this:
var filtered = $filter('lastAndFirstFilter')($scope.people, searchTerm);
```